# Knockout.js url routing

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js

I did my first knockout.js application http://jsfiddle.net/Pqs7e/

For display application parts (books section, about section) I use jquery $("#id").show(). I feel this is not right way. How can I do this through the mechanism of the viewmodel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it with special *state* observable which would identify which div to show:

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.state = ko.observable();
    ...
}
```

Then you just bind it like this:

```
<div id="books" data-bind="visible: state() === 'books'>...</div>
<div id="about" data-bind="visible: state() === 'about'>...</div>
```

and switch between states like this:

```
this.get('#books', function() {
    self.state("books");
});

this.get('#about', function() {
    self.state("about");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternate way to do this is with templates:

```
<div data-bind="template: state">
    Template renders here
</div>
```

Then your sections can be defined somewhere like this (in the same file or elsewhere):

```
<script id="books" type="text/html">
   Your markup here...
</script>

<script id="about" type="text/html">
   Your markup here...
</script>
```